# Trigger denied for a different user than I'm logged in with

Tags: mysql

I'm having some trouble with updating a rows in a table in mysql.

When I run `update table table_name set y="value" where z like "%something"`, the response is:

`ERROR 1142 (42000): TRIGGER command denied to user 'coworker'@'localhost' for table 'table_name'`

The problem is that I'm logged in as mads@localhost. I get the same error message when I log in as root, and try to do the same thing.

Does anyone know how I would solve this?

Comment: You could drop the trigger.  It sounds strange that root is not able to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger was created with the user coworker.

I guess you imported a dump with DEFINER-definitions (which contained coworker). I would remove the #DEFINER-definitions from the dump and import it again. In this case the dump will recreate the definers, but with the user who runs the import. After this the denied info shouldn't occur anymore.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this now.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much! I used the perl script from [here](http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/04/12/removing-definer-from-mysql-dump/) to help me remove the definer lines.